# Elisp Recursion Maximum Depth

Tags: recursion, emacs, elisp

I have a quick question.  I understand recursion.  I also understand why there is a need to implement a depth limit for recursion.  My question deals with the randomness of when the maximum depth error is displayed.

Consider the following method, which simply adds all numbers from 1 to the value being passed in:

```
(defun sum (x)
  (cond
   ((= x 0) 0)
   (t (+ x (sum (- x 1))))))
```

If I call:

```
(sum 50)
```

I get:

```
1275
```

If I call:

```
(sum 100)
```

I get:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (error "Lisp nesting exceeds `max-lisp-eval-depth'")
```

That's fine, but now when I dismiss the debugger and call:

```
(sum 50)
```

I get the same error message as above for `(sum 100)`.

Why does the error message seem to be coming up inconsistently?  I would assume that after I back the value back down to 50, it would calculate normally as it did prior.  Is there some flag I need to reset somewhere?  Maybe I'm simply misunderstanding the error message.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: I forgot to add that if I exit out of Emacs and open it back up, I'm able to calculate the value with 50 as the argument again, but as soon as I try the value of 100 and get the error, I can no longer use 50.

Comment: Can you reproduce this by starting Emacs with `emacs -Q` (no init file)? The latter part (getting the error for an arg of 50) does not seem right.

Comment: Yep, just tried it.  It worked for 50 initially, then I called it with 100, got the error message, backed it back down to 50 and got the error message still.

Comment: Unless someone here provides an explanation or solution, please consider filing an Emacs bug: `M-x report-emacs-bug`. The Emacs developers will let you know if this is a bug or is by design (even if reluctantly, i.e., a design limitation). And if it is a bug they might even try to fix it.

Comment: did you actually quit the debugger? Otherwise, it seems to be stuck at that level of evaluation.

Comment: @jenesaisquoi, not sure how to properly express the key combination, but I quit the debugger using `control+shift` followed by `x`, then `0`.

Comment: I don't know what you have that bound to, but I would guess `ace-window` or something similar. That isn;t quitting the debugger, try just `q` from the debugger window or select quit from its menu. You can check what function your calling there with `C-h k` `<control>-<shift> x 0` BTW

Comment: @jenesaisquoi, Yes!  This worked.  I guess I just am not entirely familiar with Emacs and its massive learning curve.  Using just `q` quits out of it when testing the value of 100 and and I can use 50 and 50 works again!  However, if at any point I use the key combination I mentioned last, then using `q` afterwards doesn't work anymore.  Is there anyway to clear out  whatever is being left behind when using `<control>-<shift> x 0` so that I don't have to exit Emacs and open it back up if I accidentally use `<control>-<shift> x 0`?

Comment: If you add this as a solution, I'll accept it!

Comment: you can call `top-level` and you should be good to go. I believe it involves resetting the internal C variable `lisp-eval-depth`

Comment: Yep.  This worked.  Thank you very much!  And as I said, if you write this up as a solution, I'll accept it!

Comment: glad it worked. Ill defer answering to a debugger expert

Comment: `C-x 0` only closes the window, it does not close the underlying buffer. A `C-x C-b` should still show you a list with the `*Backtrace* Debugger` buffer among your other buffers. You can switch to it and `q` out of the debugger.

Answer (score 1):

The `*Debugger*` buffer is a buffer like any other.  So when you use window-movement operations to switch to another buffer, it has no effect on the fact that you're within a debugging session.

You can see that in the modeline where the part showing the major mode name is surrounded by square brackets (potentially several such brackets if you're within several such `recursive-edit`s).

You can exit the debugging session by hitting `c` (for "Continue") or `q` in the `*Debugger*` buffer.  You can also exit it like any other recursive-edit, by hitting for example <kbd>ESC ESC ESC</kbd> (`keyboard-escape-quit`) or you can also use <kbd>C-]</kbd> (`abort-recursive-edit`).